# Usar validação de formulário do HTML5 junto ao Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, validação

Preciso validar um formulário usando o navegador com a propriedade `required`. Só que há um problema, meu botão de submit não fica no formulário. Ele tem que ficar fora, e quando eu clico nele eu chamo o `$('form[name="meu_form"]').submit()` e quando faço isso ele não valida utilizando o navegador.

Exemplo:

> HTML

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form name="meu_form">
   Teste campo: <input type="text" name="teste" required />
   <br />
   <button type='submit'>Enviar que valida o required</button>
</form>

<button class='btnSubmit'>Enviar que não funciona a validação do required</button>
```

> Javascript

```
//Javascript
$(function(){
    $('form[name="meu_form"]').submit(function () {
         alert('Aqui faço as chamadas ajax...');
    });

    $('.btnSubmit').click(function (){
        $('form[name="meu_form"]').submit();
    });
});
```

O problema ocorre no seguinte cenário:

Se eu deixo o `input` vazio e clico no botão dentro do `form`, ele valida, se eu clico no de fora ele simplesmente passa. Há como validar isso usando a mesma validação do `HTML`, ou eu tenho realmente que validar na mão, ou então não sei, usar um plugin por exemplo o jQuery Validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conssegui, é meio que uma gambiarra mas funcionou!

> Primeiro eu crio o botão dentro do form com `display` `none`

Após isso eu coloco o botão fora e chamo o .click com jquery no elemento que eu coloquei display none.

Segue código abaixo para vocês verem como ficou:

> HTML

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form name="meu_form">
   Teste campo: <input type="text" name="teste" required />
   <br />
   <button type='submit' class='btnOrig' style='display: none;'>Enviar que valida o required</button>
</form>

<button class='btnSubmit'>Enviar que não funciona a validação do required</button>
```

> JavaScript

```
//Javascript
$(function(){
    $('form[name="meu_form"]').submit(function () {
        alert('Aqui faço as chamadas ajax...');

        return false;
    });

    $('.btnSubmit').click(function (){
        $('.btnOrig').click();
        //$('form[name="meu_form"]').submit();
    });
});
```

**Nota: Coloquei um exemplo no JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dvtqos8t/**

Answer (score 1):

Existe um [método `checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) que faz parte da API do HTML5. Com ele podes fazer o browser verificar o elemento. Não o formulário todo, mas pelo menos os elementos um a um.

Assim no teu código podes vazer:

```
$('.btnSubmit').click(function (){
    var form = $('form[name="meu_form"]');
    var input = form.find('input[name="teste"]').get();
    if (input.checkValidity()) form.submit();
    else alert('Erro!');
});
```

Comment: Legal, mas ele não tem um método que valide o form inteiro e apresente as mensagens ?

Comment: eu posso fazer um var error = false; $('form[name="meu_form"] input, form[name="meu_form"] textarea, form[name="meu_form"] select').each(function () {   if(!$(this).checkValidity) { error = true; }  }); mas queria simplemente usar a mesma validação do HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Associe o botão ao seu formulário indicando uma `id` ao `form` e chamando ela no `button` conforme o código abaixo:

```html
<form name="meu_form" id="myForm">
   Teste campo: <input type="text" name="teste" required />
   <br />
   <button type='submit'>Enviar que valida o required</button>
</form>

<button class='btnSubmit' form="myForm">Enviar que não funciona a validação do required</button>
```